# Timeout while filling DataSet through SqlDataAdapter

Tags: c#, sql

I am fetching data from SQL through stored procedure.

In my SQL query window it takes 43 seconds to execute.

But while I am executing same stored procedure through c# I am unable to get response in 5 min.

I am using SqlDataAdapter

```
    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            // Fill the DataSet using default values for DataTable names, etc
            da.Fill(ds);

            // Detach the SqlParameters from the command object, so they can be used again
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();

            if (mustCloseConnection)
                connection.Close();

            // Return the dataset
            return ds;
        }
```

Please help me.

Comment: how do you create the cmd object?

Comment: How many rows returned after you execute your query?

Comment: @SteveB I am using SQLHelper class. you can get from  this link http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid5F6557C27DD01854BC85719A8B8A25A468393A08.aspx

Comment: 500 is not much, why it takes 43 seconds?

Comment: @CuongLe I am getting all the data in TempTable like (#tmp) and then updating that table with some logic , there is very big Sp ,also I am using function in Select command in SP.

Comment: Did you try with the OPTION RECOMPILE I gave to you ? There are great articles on the web about this : http://www.sqlpointers.com/2006/11/parameter-sniffing-stored-procedures.html

Comment: @LaGrandMere I got the problem where the error is occured. I am getting error while I am passing parameters to SP. I am passing date parameter in SP as string thats why error is occured. do u know how can I pass date parameter using DateTimePicker , my format is dd/MM/yyyy ?

Comment: @LajjaThaker : edited my answer. Tell me how you build your query cmd, and I'll be able to help you if Value doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DateTimePicker is under this format : dd/MM/yyyy.

Standard SQL dates are under this format : MM/dd/yyyy.

Use this for your SP:

```
myDateTimePicker.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: I highly doubt that this is the problem.

Comment: @Icarus : when I first read the problem, I thought about parameter sniffing, but then Lajja investigated the problem more and found there was a problem with the parameters for the SP. That's why I deleted my first answer and replied to correct his real problem. Regards.